# Convert FT232RL board from 5V to 3.3V

Tags: ftdi, 5v, 3.3v

I have a couple of these FT232RL breakout boards direct from China, look like they are [Folger](http://folger-technologies-llc.myshopify.com/products/3-3v-5-5v-ft232rl-ftdi-usb-to-ttl-serial-adapter-module-for-arduino-mini-port?variant=823021539) boards.  I measured the voltage between Vcc and GND, and it's 5V from the factory.

It has 3.3V pad on the back.  I'd like to change this to a 3.3V.

So do I solder the 3.3V pad to the center pad?  Do I have to make a cut across the 5V trace?

[image: Front]
[image: back]

Answer (score 3):

On the picture it looks like there is a small trace between the 5V and centre pads. If that is the case, you must cut it and apply a solder blob connecting the 3.3V and  centre pads.

I am not sure what this will do for the Vcc output pin. If it switches to 3.3V, be aware that you can draw only a very limited current from it.